# Update sequence when updating multiple columns in single update statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have an update query:

```
update  t
set     Col6=Col5
    ,   Col5=Col4
    ,   Col4=Col3
    ,   Col3=Col2
    ,   Col2=Col1
from    [table] t
```

Does sql do the updates in sequence? First update Col6 and then update Col5 and so on? 
I dont want to see Col1 numbers/data in Col3 in case sql updates Col2 before it updates Col3 by some sort of optimized query plan. If so I will have to write out all 5 column update statements separately.

Answer (score 5):

In general, a SQL update treats the left and right sides of the `set` as coming from two different records -- the "before" record on the right and the "after" record on the left.  In practice, most databases evaluate the set clauses in order (I'm not sure if this is required).

MySQL is different.  It evaluates the set clauses in order.  *And* references to a column after assignment are to the new value, not the old value.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

So, your statement as written is guaranteed to be evaluated in order.  Because you are not referring to already assigned values, it works as you expect and is documented to do so.

Comment: The documentation says single table update will be in sequence but multiple table update may not. So if my update was like below:
update  t1
set     t1.Col6=t1.Col5
    ,   t1.Col5=t1.Col4
    ,   t1.Col4=t1.Col3
    ,   t1.Col3=t1.Col2
    ,   t1.Col2=t1.Col1
    ,   t1.Col1=t2.Col0
from    [table1] t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id

would this be considered single table update or multiple? (I am assuming it is single)

Comment: @Abhishek . . . That would be the single table syntax.  I must emphasize, though, that that syntax is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL syntax.  If you have mislabelled this question, I would suggest that you ask *another* question clearly specifying the actual database you are using.  (This question has 4 answers all of which are based on MySQL; changing the database invalidates those answers.)

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not contain a where clause, therefore, every row will be updated.  Most relational engines work by maintaining old and new values (investigate triggers for more about this concept). The query you have created is assigning the old value stored in one column to the new value of another.

```
create table test (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);
insert into test values (1,2,3,4,5,6), (10,20,30,40,50,60);
commit;

select * from test;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
|   10 |   20 |   30 |   40 |   50 |   60 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

update  test
set Col6=Col5
,   Col5=Col4
,   Col4=Col3
,   Col3=Col2
,   Col2=Col1;
commit;

select * from test;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|   10 |   10 |   20 |   30 |   40 |   50 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As seen above, col6 contains what was in 5, 5 in 4 and so forth.  Col1 retains the original value since it was not redefined.

So what happen if we try to reference a changed value?

```
update  test
set Col1=Col2
,   Col2=Col3
,   Col3=Col4
,   Col4=Col5
,   Col5=Col6;
commit;

select * from test;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    5 |
|   10 |   20 |   30 |   40 |   50 |   50 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, MySQL assigned the appropriate values into the columns as expected.  Col6 wasn't updated since a new values was not defined.

Answer (score 0):

the assigned  column use ever the value in stored in db  row the assignment don't happen nevevr on fly

eg: if in your db row you have

```
 col5 = 1
 col4 = 3
```

the your update produce this result

```
 col6 = 1
 col5=  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
UPDATE table-name 
   SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
 WHERE condition
```